# Embarcar Tomcat em aplicação Java Desktop

Tags: java, tomcat, jar

Depois de muito penar, consegui desenvolver uma aplicação Java, com interface gráfica (swing), que simula acesso a um determinado site e extrai dados. O problema é que, como ele simula um navegador (com HtmlUnit), precisa do Tomcat e, quando eu tento rodar a aplicação em outra máquina (e vou precisar usá-lo em máquinas tanto Windows quanto MAC), ele não roda por causa do raio do Tomcat.

A pergunta é: Como eu embarco o Tomcat numa aplicação que não é Web, para que o jar seja "autossuficiente"? Eu uso o Netbeans, e, se for importante a informação, a aplicação usa bibliotecas Commons Codec do Apache, POI (do Apache) e HtmlUnit.

Comment: Talvez valha a pena, em vez do Tomcat, você dar uma olhada no Jetty.

Comment: Eu tô aceitando qualquer coisa que resolva meu problema. A questão é: Como eu embarco o servidor web na minha aplicação Java??

Answer (score -1):

Pensei em 2 soluções possíveis:

1º Solução

A) No projeto do tomcat, você faz a aplicação web, com todas as requisições que desejar.
Esse projeto, pegará os dados que você deseja e joga em um arquivo ou banco de dados.

B) O seu projeto Desktop consulta esse base de dados para obter essas informações.

--

2° Solução

Seria você fazer uma requisição ao site pelo próprio java. Através do URLConnection.
Da uma olhada nesse link: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2075162/core-java/dodge-the-traps-hiding-in-the-urlconnection-class.html

Comment: Dei uma olhada em URLConnection, mas não vi como usá-lo no meu projeto, porque o site em questão, a ser acessado, é meio complexo. Ele "se apresenta" como GEt, mas o foirmulário de login é POST (e o login é fundamental). Não bastando isso, tem uma segunda tela de login (autenticação em 2 passos) que, na verdade, é um frame da mesta tela, que, para ser acessado, é necessário ler o HTML da página, pegar um token e contruir o lkink que leva ao frame, para, depois, acioar os botões que garantem a autenticação (não, esse site não foi feito para ser acessado automaticamente por uma aplicação).

Comment: Com o HtmlUnit eu consigo simular oi navegador e ler o HTML das paginas e interagir com os elementos, mas ele me demanda o Tomcat. Consigo fazer isso só com o URLConnection (ou, mesmo que use outras bibliotecas, sem precisar do Tomcat)?

Comment: Vinicius, que tal usar a primeira opção então? assim você teria um melhor controle

Comment: Então... o problema é que não tem aplicação web no projeto. É a aplicação que acessa o site, simulando um navegador. Além do que, para isso, eu teria que embarcar o servidor e o banco de dados, além de outros recursos que a aplicação já usa... Ficaria muito pesado para a necessidade em questão

Answer (score -1):

Para esse caso, recomendo você usar o jetty embarcado, você pode iniciar o servidor junto com o start da aplicação. Você só precisa configurar e entender algumas coisas, se não tiver dificuldade com inglês, recomendo dar uma olhada nesse site que tem um exemplo de servidor embarcado com jetty.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Answer (score -1):

Já enfrentei esse problema, a minha solução foi utilizar o framewok:
http://sparkjava.com/

Ele utiliza o jetty como servidor. E ele é bem tranquilo.
No meu caso gerei um .jar do meu projeto, para iniciar na maquina do cliente era preciso somente roda o comando :

```
java -jar meuprojeto.jar
```

---

Contudo, estou percebendo q vc já tem uma aplicação toda pronta. Vc poderia gerar um .exe(para o windows) utilizando o http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php, a logica seria a seguinte:

1. Vc seleciona os arquivos q ele tem q copiar para a maquina do cliente. Vc compilar o seu projeto(.war) em um tomcat.No ato da instalação do seu executavel, ele irá copiar  esse tomcat para o seu cliente.
2. Vc também poder informar o comando q ele deve executar, quando terminar de copiar o projeto para uma pasta de instalação.Ou seja, ele ira iniciar o seu tomcat.
3. Cuidado com a porta q vc irar iniciar o seu tomcat na maquina do seu cliente.Pois ela poderá esta em uso.

---

Uma outra solução também seria utilizar o spring-boot, ele ja vem com um tomcat embarcado. Vc iria compilar o seu projeto normalmente, no final das contas ele gera um .jar e vc rodaria o projeto da seguinte forma :

```
 java -jar seuprojeto.jar
```

Comment: Estou tentando o spring-boot, mas parece que ele só faz aplicação web... é isso msm? Se for, não é o caso, Minha aplicação tem que ser desktop msm...

Comment: Ele gerar um .jar. Vc pode rodar a sua aplicação "java -jar seuprojeto.jar", so tem q tomar cuidado com a porta q ela vai rodar.